# Spring data mongo query to aggregate(Distinct) with pagination

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

Given we have following documents in database

```
{id:0, SID:0, STATUS:"UNDONE", UID:1, AT:122}
{id:1, SID:1, STATUS:"DONE", UID:1, AT:123}
{id:2, SID:1, STATUS:"DONE", UID:2, AT:124}
{id:3, SID:2, STATUS:"PEN", UID:3, AT:125}
{id:4, SID:2, STATUS:"PEN", UID:4, AT:126}
{id:5, SID:3, STATUS:"DONE", UID:5, AT:127}
{id:6, SID:4, STATUS:"DONE", UID:6, AT:128}
```

I'm trying to get write a query using spring data mongodb to skip 'm' distinct SID and get next 'n' distinct SID (Sorted by AT field) matching the filter and return documents corresponding to those SIDs.

For this example m = 1 and n = 2 would return these documents

```
{id:3, SID:2, STATUS:"PEN", UID:3, AT:125}
{id:4, SID:2, STATUS:"PEN", UID:4, AT:126}
{id:5, SID:3, STATUS:"DONE", UID:5, AT:127}
```

So far I've managed to write this.

```
Aggregation aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(
                Aggregation.project("STATUS", "AT", "SID"),
                Aggregation.match(Criteria.where("STATUS").in("DONE", "PEN")),
                Aggregation.sort(Sort.Direction.DESC, "AT"),
                Aggregation.group("SID"),
                Aggregation.skip(skip),
                Aggregation.limit(limit));

        AggregationResults<Map> results = mongoOperations.aggregate(aggregation, MyClass.class, Map.class);
        List<String> SIDs = results.getMappedResults().stream().map(it -> it.get("_id").toString()).collect(Collectors.toList());

        Query query = new Query();
        query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("SID").in(SIDs));
        return mongoOperations.find(query, MyClass.class);
```

This is returning unpredictable results ie every call returns different results and therefore not sorted as intended.

What am I missing here?
I've a feeling the sort stage in pipeline is incorrectly placed.

Comment: perhaps if you group first, then sort. The grouping is a blocking operation and will impact the results, so sorting after grouping will then produce results in predictable order.

Comment: A better approach to pagination when compared to skip/limit is to remember the prior last record, then add a filter to the next page's query that removes these from the result set.  Skip and limit work well for low skip values, but are slow for high skip values as the cursor needs to iterate deep.  Even better - keep the cursor for the next page and grab the next page's results by iterating the cursor further.